# Plotting timeseries data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix that contains two columns of data. The first column has timestamps given in UNIX time and the second column has a corresponding data set.

I'm trying to plot this `DATA` with human-readable times on the bottom axis.

I've plotted the raw data, like so:

```
plot(DATA(:,1), DATA(:,2));
```

I know there is a [`timeseries()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseries-class.html) function in MATLAB, but I can't seem to get it working correctly. I should be able to plot the data, [following the MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseries.plot.html).

I've tried declaring the first column as a time series:

```
TS = timeseries(DATA(:,1));
```

Then I tried plotting the data, like so:

```
plot(TS, DATA(:,1));
```

Although this approach seems to make rational sense, I get the following error:

> Error using plot
>   Data must be a single matrix Y or a list of pairs X,Y

I also tried to use the [`addsample()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseries.addsample.html) function to append the data to the time series and then plot it.

```
K = addsample(TS, DATA(:,2));
plot(K);
```

But doing this produced the following error:

> A new sample must be specified either as a structure or by Property-Value pairs.

So how do I plot this time data correctly? Thank you!

Comment: I don't think `timeseries` is the correct function for this, since it uses only the data as input and the equidistant time-steps (although some can be missing). However, if you have arbitrary time points, it will not work as expected. Can you add sample data, i.e. the first four lines of `DATA`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work quite often with `posix` time (i.e. `unixtime`) with other programs, but in matlab the easiest format to deal with time and date is the Matlab time serial number format.

To convert from `Unix` to `Matlab` I use a small conversion function extensively:

```
function matlabtime = unix2matlabtime(unixtime)
%// function matlabtime = unix2matlabtime(unixtime)
%//
%// input : ** unixtime ** : time vector in the UNIX  time serial number
%//                          representation (seconds since 01-jan-1970)
%//
%// output : ** matlabtime **  : time vector in the Matlab time serial number
%//                          representation (days since 01-jan-0000)

pivot = datenum([1970 01 01 00 00 00]) ;
matlabtime = ( unixtime / 24 / 3600 ) + pivot ;
```

---

with this function saved somewhere on your path, you can plot your data like so:

```
%// Generate sample data
sampleunixtime = linspace( 1427205640 , 1427205900 ).' ;         %'// ignore this comment
DATA = [sampleunixtime , sin(sampleunixtime./10) ]  ;

%// get a time vector in Matlab time serial format, then plot
time = unix2matlabtime( DATA(:,1) ) ;
plot( time, DATA(:,2) ) 

%// Adjust X-Ticks in human readable format
set( gca , 'XTickLabel' , datestr( get(gca,'XTick'),'HH:MM:SS' ) )
```

To obtain:

[image: imgexample]

look at the [`datenum`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) and [`datestr`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) documentation to see how to handle these. There are many predefined output format for the date/time or you can even build your own to refine to the precision you need (add millisecond, remove seconds, add the date etc ...).

Just be aware that the `XTickLabel` are now overriden, so they will not be updated automatically. So if you `zoom` or `pan` on your figure you'll have to re-run the last line of code to refresh the `XTicks` values.

(*personally, I put this last line of code in a Matlab toolbar shortcut to have quick access to it at any time*).